# Why is `smartctl -l xerror` LBA well beyond end of disk?

Tags: hard-disk, sata, smartctl, smart

I ran `smartctl -l xerror` on a Seagate ST31000528AS (1TB disk with 512-byte sectors), and it gave me (in part):

```
Error 597 [16] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 11903 hours (495 days + 23 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 74 59 00 70 bc 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x74590070bc = 499709407420

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 00 00 08 00 74 59 00 70 b8 40 00 12d+16:57:44.392  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00 12d+16:57:40.893  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00 12d+16:57:40.801  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  61 00 00 00 08 00 08 a8 00 43 18 40 00 12d+16:57:40.800  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 00 00 08 00 08 af 00 40 68 40 00 12d+16:57:40.800  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
```

I'm really confused what this means—in particular the LBA48 it's giving. `hdparm -I` confirms the disk has 1,953,525,168 sectors; 499,709,407,420 is *well* beyond that. (It'd need a disk of 256TB to be valid, even with 512-byte sectors.)

Judging from the kernel logs, the LBA48 is probably actually 1,953,520,060 — testing with `dd` and `hdparm --read-sector` confirm that sector is indeed bad. (Indeed, that one also shows up in `smartctl -l xselftest`).

Why is the extended error log giving an LBA48 that appears to be almost 256 (but not quite!) times greater than the real value? Looking at the hex values, it appears the bytes are in the wrong order—is this maybe just a drive firmware bug?

Comment: Hve you checked to see if there is a firmware update for this drive?

Comment: @Joe according to https://apps1.seagate.com/downloads/request.html?userPreferredLocaleCookie=en_US_ there is no firmware update.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at those numbers in binary, 499709407420 and 1953520060.

```
echo "obase=2;499709407420" | bc
111010001011001000000000111000010111100
echo "obase=2;1953520060" | bc
1110100011100000101100110111100
```

split that into a few groups:

```
11101000
        1110000
               0
                1011001
                       10111100
```

rearrange a bit:

```
11101000
                        1110000
                0
        1011001
                               10111100
```

and it's very similar to:

```
111010001011001000000000111000010111100
```

Seems like probably more than a coincidence but maybe I'm just seeing something that isn't there.